# How to make a filter based on selected items

Tags: java, android, listview, filter

can somebody tell me how to make a filter based on selected items in a ListView?
In MainActivity I've got a ListView with items and in SecondActivity I've got ListView with results. For example items: `"wood", "leather", "steel" ...`
and results: `"wooden chair", "wooden boat",  "wooden and steel chair" "steel sword", "jacket"`
If wood is selected I need to get in ListView `"wooden chair", "wooden boat"` but other must be invisible. If wood and steel are selected I need to get in ListView `"wooden chair", "wooden boat", wooden and steel chair", "steel sword"` etc. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data from on activity using the intents as-

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.clas);
        intent.putExtra("key_data","value_data");
        startActivity(intent);
```

You can receive the data in your second activity as-

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
        String data_value=intent.getStringExtra("key_valle");
```

And now you can filter the results based upon the data from the previous activity.

**NOTE:** 
If you should use database if you are not using for the easy implementations.

Comment: But my problem is to make strict filter like this.

Comment: Create tables in sqlite database for the category and the products and show the category in the first activity and after the selection pass the ids to the next activity and then query the database and  populate the list.